# ES6 js "with" keyword

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6

In the deep internet I encountered structure like `class A extends B with C { ... }`, I haven't link right now, it was like macro for class while extending abstract class.

Is this in standard? (I googled, only finding old `with` that is removed right now, chrome inline console throws error)

Comment: Can you please link where you found it? No, it's not in ES7, though it was part of many class proposals.

Comment: Probably it was a proposal, because if I will be able to find it once more - I will not ask this question.

Comment: [This article](http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/) references [Dart's mixin syntax](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/mixins) in terms of ES6 classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not standard. From [Annex A.4 - Functions and Classes](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functions-and-classes), the syntax is

```
ClassDeclaration[Yield, Default] :
    class BindingIdentifier[?Yield] ClassTail[?Yield]
    [+Default] class ClassTail[?Yield]

ClassExpression[Yield] :
    class BindingIdentifier[?Yield]opt ClassTail[?Yield]

ClassTail[Yield] :
    ClassHeritage[?Yield]opt { ClassBody[?Yield]opt }

ClassHeritage[Yield] :
    extends LeftHandSideExpression[?Yield]
```

So the *ClassTail* is the part which includes both the optional `extends something` and the class body. And that `something` must be a *LeftHandSideExpression*, without any `with` in there.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not a part of the ECMAScript 6 Classes standard.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

The `with` keyword is used in some programming languages to signify multiple inheritance.

Scala for example has traits which classes can extend from with the `with` keyword

```
trait Drawable {
    def draw() { }
}

trait Cowboy extends Drawable {
    override def draw() { println("Bang!") }
}

trait Artist extends Drawable {
    override def draw() { println("A pretty painting") }
}


class CowboyArtist extends Cowboy with Artist
```